# Rotate javascript cube on drag & on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, 3d, rotation

Here is my problem: 
I've been trying to do this CSS cube turn on scroll. And I did it! Here is how it worked: https://codepen.io/vaninoo/pen/BmyYQd

I was very happy. But after testing it with friends, it seems that many of them wanted to "Drag" the cube to make it rotate. So I decided to add this feature. This is the closest I got: https://codepen.io/vaninoo/pen/jaEZBx

The cube is rotatable on drag, and after I dragged it I can rotate it by scrolling. But:

1. I'd like it to turn whenever I scroll, even without clicking before.
2. I can't figure out how to remove that "jump" when I move it. It needs to keep the position of the cube in memory but I tried very hard and just couldn't do it.

Here is the code you can find on my pen (the "closest I got"):

```js
// START OF UNSURE PART

$('document').ready(function() {
 var lastScrollTop = 0;
 $(window).scroll(function trucenscroll(event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sl = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        
        //Le cube tourne
      var p1,angle,i,tmp;
   
   p1 = {'x': sl - p0.x, 'y': st - p0.y }, 
   angle = {'x': -p1.y * unit,  'y': p1.x * unit};
    
   for(i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) 
   {
    tmp = 'rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg)' + ' rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];
    faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
    faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
   }
    }
    else if(st == lastScrollTop) {
      //do nothing 
      //In IE this is an important condition because there seems to be some instances where the last scrollTop is equal to the new one
    }
    else {
      var p1,angle,i,tmp;
   p1 = {'x': sl - p0.x, 'y': st - p0.y }, 
   angle = {'x': -p1.y * unit,  'y': p1.x * unit};
    
   for(i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) 
   {
    tmp = 'rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg)' + ' rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];
    faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
    faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
   }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
 });
});


// END OF UNSURE PART








init();  
//===========================================================
//   onMouseMove
//===========================================================
function onMouseMove(e) 
{
 var p1,angle,i,tmp;

 if (! dragging) return;

 p1 = {'x': e.clientX - p0.x, 'y': e.clientY - p0.y }, 
 angle = {'x': -p1.y * unit,  'y': p1.x * unit};
  
 for(i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) 
 {
  tmp = 'rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg)' + ' rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];
  faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
  faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
 }
}
//===========================================================
//   onMouseDown
//===========================================================
function onMouseDown(e)
{
 var element;

 onMouseUp(); // disable if dragging

 element = e.target;
 //if (! element.classList.contains('face')) return false;

 e.preventDefault();
 window.p0 = { 'x': e.clientX, 'y': e.clientY };
 dragging = true;
 return false;
}
//===========================================================
//   onMouseUp
//===========================================================
function onMouseUp(e)
{
 var i,tmp,style;

 if (! dragging) return;
 dragging = false; 

 for ( i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) 
 {
  style = faces[i].style;
  tmp = style.transform || style['-webkit-transform'];
  styles[i] = tmp.replace('perspective(32em) ', '');
 }
  
}
//=====================================================================
//   initializeCube
//=====================================================================
function initializeCube()
{
 var i,tmp;

 for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++)
 {
  if (i  < 4) tmp = 'rotateY(' + i*90 + 'deg)';
  if (i >= 4) tmp = 'rotateX(' + Math.pow(-1, i) * 90 + 'deg)';
  tmp += ' translateZ(' + side/2 + 'px)';
 
  faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
  faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
  styles.push(tmp);
 }
}
//=====================================================================
//   init
//=====================================================================
function init()
{
 window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
 window.addEventListener('mouseup',   onMouseUp,   false);
 window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);

 window.faces   = document.querySelectorAll('.face');
 window.styles   = new Array();
 window.style   = getComputedStyle(faces[0]);
 window.factor   = 3;
 window.side   = parseInt(style.width.split('px')[0], 10);
 window.max_amount  = factor * side; 
 window.unit   = 360 / max_amount;
 window.dragging  = false;
 window.scrolling  = false;
 window.p   = 'perspective(32em)';

 initializeCube();
}
```

```css
body {
 position: relative;
 height:5000px;
}

.cube, .cube * 
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 50%;
}
  
.cube 
{
  user-select: none;
  cursor: move;
}
.cube div span
{
 position: relative;
 top: 60px;
 left: -5px;
 font-size: 8em;
}

.face 
{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: solid 1px;
 margin: -8em;
 width: 16em;
 height: 16em;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,255,0.6);
 text-align: center;
 /** backface-visibility: hidden; /**/
}
.face:nth-child(1) { 
 background: rgba(255,   0,   0, 0.2); 
}
.face:nth-child(2) { background: rgba(255, 255,   0, 0.2); }
.face:nth-child(3) { background: rgba(  0, 255,   0, 0.2); }
.face:nth-child(4) { background: rgba(  0, 255, 255, 0.2); }
.face:nth-child(5) { background: rgba(  0,   0, 255, 0.2); }
.face:nth-child(6) { background: rgba(255,   0, 255, 0.2); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body translate="no" onload="init()">
<div class='cube' id="cubo">
  <div class='face'><span>1</span></div>
  <div class='face'><span>2</span></div>
  <div class='face'><span>3</span></div>
  <div class='face'><span>4</span></div>
  <div class='face'><span>5</span></div>
  <div class='face'><span>6</span></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi! I converted your question's code into a snippit (the `{}` button in the question editor toolbar) that allows us to embed and run the code right in the question, and copy the runnable code to answers easily.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much, I'll do it next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this should be the behavior that you want. You had failed to initialize the `p0` variable in your code so when you tried scrolling immediately without clicking it would throw errors. Also, the jump you were seeing is because after you set `p0` in your `onMouseDown` function, you never set it back to your initial state (which I just set to `{x:0, y:0}`) so the scrolling would start based in the `p0` value your mouse had set.

Going into more detail. In your `$(document).ready()` I set an initial state for the p0 variable to `window.p0={'x':0,'y':0}`. I then also reset the p0 variable in the `onMouseUp` function to ensure that if you stop dragging and start scrolling again, it is set correctly.

Also, I have modified the scroll function to include storing the states of the style of the cube faces. I believe that, because the `$(window).scroll` function was not storing the style states it was applying, the dragging was essentially "losing" the last state of the cubes which was causing the jumping you were noticing. Please note that this change could cause some overload though as it is continually appending to the styles that get applied to the cube faces at a rapid rate.

```js
// START OF UNSURE PART

$('document').ready(function() {
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  //Set the initial state of window.p0 so that scrolling works without clicking
  window.p0 = {
    'x': 0,
    'y': 0
  };
  $(window).scroll(function trucenscroll(event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sl = $(this).scrollLeft();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {

      //Le cube tourne
      var p1, angle, i, tmp;

      p1 = {
          'x': sl - p0.x,
          'y': st - p0.y
        },
        angle = {
          'x': -p1.y * unit,
          'y': p1.x * unit
        };
      for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        tmp = 'rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg)' + ' rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];
        faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
        faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
        //Save the state of the style of the cube faces. This ensures that if you switch to dragging, then there will be no jumps because all of the transforms will still be correctly applied.
        style = faces[i].style;
        var tmpStyle = style.transform || style['-webkit-transform'];
        styles[i] = tmpStyle.replace('perspective(32em) ', '');
      }
    } else if (st == lastScrollTop) {
      //do nothing 
      //In IE this is an important condition because there seems to be some instances where the last scrollTop is equal to the new one
    } else {
      var p1, angle, i, tmp;
      p1 = {
          'x': sl - p0.x,
          'y': st - p0.y
        },
        angle = {
          'x': -p1.y * unit,
          'y': p1.x * unit
        };

      for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        tmp = 'rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg)' + ' rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];
        faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
        faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
        //Save the state of the style of the cube faces. This ensures that if you switch to dragging, then there will be no jumps because all of the transforms will still be correctly applied.
        style = faces[i].style;
        var tmpStyle = style.transform || style['-webkit-transform'];
        styles[i] = tmpStyle.replace('perspective(32em) ', '');
      }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
});


// END OF UNSURE PART








init();
//===========================================================
//   onMouseMove
//===========================================================
function onMouseMove(e) {
  var p1, angle, i, tmp;

  if (!dragging) return;

  p1 = {
      'x': e.clientX - p0.x,
      'y': e.clientY - p0.y
    },
    angle = {
      'x': -p1.y * unit,
      'y': p1.x * unit
    };
  for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    tmp = 'rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg)' + ' rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];
    faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
    faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
  }
}
//===========================================================
//   onMouseDown
//===========================================================
function onMouseDown(e) {
  var element;

  onMouseUp(); // disable if dragging

  element = e.target;
  //if (! element.classList.contains('face')) return false;

  e.preventDefault();
  window.p0 = {
    'x': e.clientX,
    'y': e.clientY
  };
  dragging = true;
  return false;
}
//===========================================================
//   onMouseUp
//===========================================================
function onMouseUp(e) {
  var i, tmp, style;

  if (!dragging) return;
  dragging = false;

  //Save the state of the style of the cube faces. This ensures that if you switch to dragging, then there will be no jumps because all of the transforms will still be correctly applied.
  for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    style = faces[i].style;
    tmp = style.transform || style['-webkit-transform'];
    styles[i] = tmp.replace('perspective(32em) ', '');
  }
  //Reset the window.p0 variable back for scrolling to work
  window.p0 = {
    'x': 0,
    'y': 0
  };

}
//=====================================================================
//   initializeCube
//=====================================================================
function initializeCube() {
  var i, tmp;

  for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    if (i < 4) tmp = 'rotateY(' + i * 90 + 'deg)';
    if (i >= 4) tmp = 'rotateX(' + Math.pow(-1, i) * 90 + 'deg)';
    tmp += ' translateZ(' + side / 2 + 'px)';

    faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
    faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
    styles.push(tmp);
  }
}
//=====================================================================
//   init
//=====================================================================
function init() {
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);

  window.faces = document.querySelectorAll('.face');
  window.styles = new Array();
  window.style = getComputedStyle(faces[0]);
  window.factor = 3;
  window.side = parseInt(style.width.split('px')[0], 10);
  window.max_amount = factor * side;
  window.unit = 360 / max_amount;
  window.dragging = false;
  window.scrolling = false;
  window.p = 'perspective(32em)';

  initializeCube();
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 5000px;
}

.cube,
.cube * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 50%;
}

.cube {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: move;
}

.cube div span {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: -5px;
  font-size: 8em;
}

.face {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: -8em;
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
  /** backface-visibility: hidden; /**/
}

.face:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.face:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.face:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgba( 0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.face:nth-child(4) {
  background: rgba( 0, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.face:nth-child(5) {
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

.face:nth-child(6) {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body translate="no" onload="init()">
  <div class='cube' id="cubo">
    <div class='face'><span>1</span></div>
    <div class='face'><span>2</span></div>
    <div class='face'><span>3</span></div>
    <div class='face'><span>4</span></div>
    <div class='face'><span>5</span></div>
    <div class='face'><span>6</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate on the changes you made a bit?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! 
It's a LOT better but I'm still getting "jumps" 90% of the time when alternating scroll and drag. I understand the p0 problem you're talking about. Seems like it's sometimes working so I'm trying to figure out when and how.
EDIT : Seems to happen maily when the window is scrolled and I'm dragging it.

Comment: @msanford let me know if those edits answer your questions. I also added comments in the code for the specific locations I made changes.

Comment: Like I stated the problem appears to be with maintaining the state of the transformations applied when scrolling. As it is difficult to tell if a user is "done" scrolling it is hard to know when to save the state. This currently saves all states when scrolling, but can quickly grow to a huge amount of transforms.

Comment: @Joffutt Excellent; thank you. It helps to zero-in on what actually solved the issue, especially with this much code. +1

Comment: Thank you @Joffutt!